# Index of first occurrence of all remaining columns =0 after first occurrence of x> value

Tags: r

I have a matrix and I need to find the index that matches the following conditions:
1.The first time a value is greater than 90 (first90)
2. The index for the column corresponding to the first occurrence of the value zero following first90 and the remaining entries in the column are all zero.

For example, in df.ex, the rows meeting these conditions are 2 and 4. The correct column index is 5 for row 2 and 4 for row 4.
Rows 1 and 3 have entries over 90, but some of the columns to the right of those are non-zero (30 in row 1, 20 and 49 in row 3).
Got the first part using max col, struggling on the second part.
Any ideas appreciated.

```
df.ex=matrix(c(
        0,57,92,0,30,0,
        190,99,30,100,0,0,
        0,91,0,0,20,49,
        15,121,0,0,0,0),
        nrow=4,ncol=6,byrow=T)

first.oc<-max.col(df.ex > 90, "first")
```

Update: edited the matrix. To make it a bit clearer (been looking at this too long). I m looking for the index of the column after the first time the value is greater than 90 (have that) and where the remaining entries of the row are zero. In the slightly changed example,  for row 4, col 2 >90, I m looking for a way to find the index for col 3 (0 followed by consecutive 0's).

Comment: What is the expected outcome for your example?

Comment: Hi, a vector of column indices. These can be combined with the rows to subset the matrix.

Comment: Are you looking for a logical vector that identifies rows in which the conditions are met, or a vector with the column number in each row that satisfies your conditions (and, presumably, something like NA for rows where the conditions are not satisfied)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Yes thats correct column numbers. I had tried apply(df.ex,2,function(x,first.oc) which((x > first.oc)==0)[1],first.oc=first.oc) but not working as expected.  Max.col returns the first >90, I'd like to find the columns that contain consecutive zeros to the end of the row, at some point past the first 90.  In row 2 above, >90 is column 2, the last two columns in row 2 are both zero, so I'd like the index of the first 0 - column 5. In row 4, it will be column 4 - the first 0 following 60. I can edit the matrix to make this clearer.

Comment: What should the index show for rows 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
df.ex.t <- as.data.frame(t(df.ex))
above.90 <- sapply(df.ex.t, function(x) which.max(x > 90))
trailing.0 <- sapply(df.ex.t, function(x) which.max(rev(x) > 0))
index <- as.logical(trailing.0 > above.90)
first.0 <- sapply(df.ex.t[,index], function(x) which.max(x == 0))
```

Result:

```
> first.0
V2 V4 
 5  4
```